# Radiance definition

Tags: optics, radiometry

I have been trying very hard to get my head around how the radiance definition is illustrated on the web.

Every website puts the apex of the solid angle on the surface, but the definition said the solid angle is one into which the patch dA on the surface emits the light.

So referring to the picture below, shouldn't the cone be placed like the one on the right rather than the one on the left?

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSoTz.png)

Below is an example how the solid angle's apex is placed on the surface rather than below the surface on the web.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Etendue_for_differential_surface_element_in_2D_and_3D.png

Comment: The RP Photonics Encylopedia has a good article on [Radiance](https://www.rp-photonics.com/radiance.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it doesn't seem to explain my question though